# AMP Form custom-validation-reporting interact-and-submit

Tags: amp-html

The below error is shown when I put: ***custom-validation-reporting="interact-and-submit"*** into AMP Form. But it works. Is it really invalid?

*The attribute 'custom-validation-reporting' in tag 'FORM [method=POST]' is set to the invalid value 'interact-and-submit'.*

Comment: Maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10773) can help you find your way to a solution.

Comment: It said "The validator changes are now in production.". But the validator still shows error

Comment: When I use #development=1 to validate, it works.

Comment: Iam glad you found a solution for your problem :-) The best next step would be to post it as an answer to your question and accept it, so others can see that your problem has been solved and that an solution is available.